# How to serialize ArrayList<Object> to String in Java Android

Tags: android, serialization, sharedpreferences

This question was asked many times, but I haven't found a good solution yet.
I want to store my Arraylist in the sharedpreferences in Android as a String. So how can I serialize and deserialize it?

Any solutions?

Comment: What are the objects in the list? Are they from your own custom class?

Comment: Yes, they are from my own custom class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save ArrayList to SharedPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)

Comment: That post describes the same solution you accepted, so I'm not sure what you meant by "haven't found a good solution yet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Gson Library](https://github.com/google/gson) this way:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(<your list>);
```

To add Gson library add to dependencies

```
compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2"
```

Comment: Version `2.8.0` is the latest Gson, as of those post

Comment: Good catch! not using Gson lately

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a toString() method for your custom objects then call toString() on the ArrayList. Parsing the string to deserialize it will be more difficult.